# Position table content vertical

Tags: html, css, twig

I have a created a table and placed a circle in a column to show if someone is online or offline.

The circles where created with CSS.

I want to vertical align the circle in the middle and I tried :

```
vertical-algin: middle;
display: table-cell;
```

But nothing happens.

My CSS Code :

```
.circle {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.online {
    background: #5CB85C;
}
.offline {
    background: #D9534F;
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEMS7.jpg

http://jsfiddle.net/x0eqyjrn

Comment: did you add margin: 0 auto;?

Comment: @Keith He is trying to vertically align not horizontal alignment.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You know you have a typo...right? `vertical-algin: middle;`

Comment: Here is a example 
https://jsfiddle.net/x0eqyjrn/

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of CSS3 flexible box layout instead. Just `align-items: center` will vertically align the status circles. No need to set `vertical-align`.

```css
.container {
  height: 30px;
  background: lightgray;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.container:nth-child(odd) {
  background: white;
}
.circle {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.online {
  background: #5CB85C;
}
.offline {
  background: #D9534F;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle online">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="circle offline">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="circle offline">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="circle online">
  </div>
</div>
```